# NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 4 project, incorporating NHibernate 3.3. I have two classes declared as follows (simplified for brevity):

```
public class LocationReading
{
    public long Timestamp { get; set; }
    public GeoLocation Location { get; set; }
}

public class GeoLocation
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}

public class RoutePoint
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Username { get; set; }
    public virtual LocationReading LocationReading { get; set; }
}
```

and mapped as follows:

```
<class name="RoutePoint">

<id name="Id" type="Int32" column="id"  unsaved-value="0">
  <generator class="hilo"/>
</id>

<property name="Username"/>

<component name="LocationReading" >
  <property name="Timestamp"/>
  <component name="Location">
    <property name="Latitude"/>
    <property name="Longitude"/>
  </component>
</component>
```

I get

```
NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException: Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.MismatchedTreeNodeException' was thrown.
```

anytime I attempt a query via linq to nhibernate, like for example:

```
int count = session.Query<RoutePoint>().Where(p => p.LocationReading != null).Count();
```

I think the nested component mapping is causing the error. Any ideas?

Update:
I decided, that I should've updated all referenced components first, so I did and just got the latest versions of NHibernate and Npgsql from NuGet, and I still have the exception, which now somewhat differs though. I now have:

```
NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException
{"A recognition error occurred. [.Count[RoutePoint](.Where[RoutePoint](NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[RoutePoint], Quote((p, ) => (NotEqual(p.LocationReading, NULL))), ), )]"}
```

Comment: I have a similar problem.  It seems that Linq2NHibernate won't let you query on `.ComponentName != null`.  Interestingly you can query on a non-null property of the component (in your case `p.LocationReading.Timestamp != null` and this works, though your IDE will probably yell at you saying "Expression is always true".